# Editing a website made with wordpress

Tags: customization

can i edit a website made with WordPress by another person? because a company want me to help them mentain their website and it was built with WordPress

Comment: Yes, of course - as long as they give you a login to the site with enough permissions.

Comment: Did you mean maintain the content, or the actual code and functionality? If it's the latter, hopefully they'll also give you access to the server's filesystem, database and logs, or at least a copy of the database and any custom plugins or themes in use.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has many roles and you can tell your client to assign to the role according to your work responsibility. If he is ok with FTP then no worries, otherwise you can have one from the below:

There are role according to each work like

- Super Admin – somebody with access to the site network administration
  features and all other features. See the Create a Network article.
- Administrator – somebody who has access to all the administration
  features within a single site.
- Editor – somebody who can publish and manage posts including the
  posts of other users.
- Author  – somebody who can publish and manage their own posts.
- Contributor – somebody who can write and manage their own posts but
  cannot publish them.
- Subscriber  – somebody who can only manage their profile.

More details can be found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/)